# Compiling libavg on Raspberry Pi2

Tags: compiler-errors, raspberry-pi, libavg

I want to build libavg on my new RaspberryPi2.

My steps are,

```
1.) git clone https://github.com/libavg/libavg.git libavg
2.) cd libavg
3.) ./bootstrap
4.) ./configure --enable-rpi --prefix=/home/pi/raspberryPi2/install_release
```

That results in a error.

```
  CXXLD  testgraphics
  CXX    testgpu.o
  CXXLD  testgpu
  /usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libgraphics.a(BCMDisplay.o): undefined reference to symbol 'vc_dispmanx_element_add'
  //opt/vc/lib/libbcm_host.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  Makefile:668: recipe for target 'testgpu' failed
  make[4]: *** [testgpu] Error 1
  make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/raspberryPi2/libavg/src/graphics'
  Makefile:795: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
  make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/raspberryPi2/libavg/src/graphics'
  Makefile:385: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
  make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
  make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/raspberryPi2/libavg/src'
  Makefile:323: recipe for target 'all' failed
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/raspberryPi2/libavg/src'
  Makefile:389: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
  make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Try adding `-lbcm_hosts`

Comment: In the makefile?? Which LIBS var? Or in the configure step?

Answer (score 0):

The Error is from the modified makefile. Without that file, libavg build’s correctly.
In the modified Makefile, libavg is compiled with libbrowsernode support.
Is there a way to do that?

modified File: src/test/plugin/Makefile.am

```
pkgpyexec_LTLIBRARIES = colorplugin.la libbrowsernode.la
colorplugin_la_SOURCES = ColorNode.cpp
colorplugin_la_LDFLAGS = $(EXTRA_LDFLAGS) -module
libbrowsernode_la_SOURCES = BrowserNode.cpp
libbrowsernode_la_LDFLAGS = -lberkelium_delegate $(EXTRA_LDFLAGS) -module
```

org. File:

```
pkgpyexec_LTLIBRARIES = colorplugin.la
colorplugin_la_SOURCES = ColorNode.cpp
colorplugin_la_LDFLAGS = $(EXTRA_LDFLAGS) -module
```

Answer (score 0):

libavg needed to be updated to run with the current RPi system. The issue is fixed in the current git head of libavg, so you just need to do a git pull and recompile.

The changes necessary are here: https://github.com/libavg/libavg/commit/d7f785347c90ada2daf02afffaac178bb705607b